# Redirecting to AngularJS route after success payment

Tags: angularjs, node.js, payumoney

I am integrating PayUMoney app in my mean stack application.Now after payment is successfully done payumoney calls my success api.
Now i need to render the response of this api call to my angularjs view page.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: my success call is done by payumoney not by my angularjs app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the response returned from the PayUMoney are a few parameters like `success=true&transactionId=2342418083&ref=18`.

So when you receive these parameters in your server side code, redirect the user to the Angular page with those as query parameter like:

```
// TODO this is a Grails way of redirect, do according to your app
redirect(uri: "/#/payment/success?success=true&transactionId=2342418083&ref=18")
```

Now, in the Angular controller of `payment/success` page, you can use `$location` service to get those parameters:

```
fooApp.controller("PaymentSuccessController", function($scope, $location) {
    var params = $location.search();
    // Now use these paramters
    console.log(params.transactionId == "2342418083");
});
```

Comment: this is what i am doing i made redirect as   res.redirect('/success?orderId='+payment_details.orderId+'&txn_id='+payment_details.txn_id);

Comment: and my controller   console.log('coming');
      var params = $location.search();
      console.log(params);